# How to make htaccess demand a password on one domain (or IP) but not another

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, .htpasswd

I have a website that works like this:

- dev.website.com (hosted @ 1.1.1.1)
- phil.website.com (hosted @ 1.1.1.2)
- www.website.com (hosted @ 1.1.1.3 & 1.1.1.4 served from load balancer @ 1.1.1.5)

They all use file that has these lines:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/website.com/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I want to make it so that there is no password required for users looking at the load balancer. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mod_envif` directives:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^(1\.1.\1\.3|1\.1.\1\.4)$ NO_AUTH

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/website.com/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Satisfy    any
Order      deny,allow
Deny from  all
Allow from env=NO_AUTH
```

Comment: so "Remote_Addr" doesn't get confused by the load balancer?

Comment: Naw it doesn't work, I'm trying to get into the logs now.

Comment: Isn't REMOTE_ADDR for the IP of the user? I am trying to look at the host.

Comment: Yes but sometimes proxies and load balancers send their IPs as `REMOTE_ADDR`

Comment: Ahh I see, LB was setting it to 127.0.0.1 So I included that. So can someone still come to dev.website.com and somehow pretend to be coming from 127.0.0.1 and then bypass the auth?

Comment: No that's not possible because `127.0.0.1` is localhost address and cannot be used by any outsider